# "TypeError: color must be int, or tuple of one, three or four elements" on Pillow colorize method

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've been trying to paste a skewed letter using a mask from PIL library.

```
import cv2
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageOps
import numpy as np
import random

def generate_new(text: str="") -> Image.Image:
    captcha = 243*np.ones(shape=[30,100,3], dtype=np.uint8)
    font = "/content/drive/MyDrive/captchas/qwerty.ttf"
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font, 22)
    #Create a field for digits to be drawn to
    captcha = Image.fromarray(243*np.ones(shape=[30,100,3], dtype=np.uint8))
    #Generate every single digit
    x = 10
    for symbol in text:
      #Create a field to draw a digit on
      digit = Image.new("L",(30,30))
      cursor = ImageDraw.Draw(digit)
      cursor.text((10, 0),  symbol, font = font, fill = 255)
      digit_rotated = digit.rotate(random.randrange(-70,70), PIL.Image.NEAREST,  expand=0)
      digit_rotated.show()
>>>   Image.Image.paste(ImageOps.colorize(digit_rotated, (0,0,0), (255,255,255)), (x,6), digit_rotated)
      x+=30
    return captcha

captcha = generate_new("12345")
captcha.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/captchas/12345.png")
```

After running the code I'm getting

> TypeError: color must be int, or tuple of one, three or four elements

which I understand to be an issue with positional arguments. thrown by `Image.Image.paste` method.

I've tried consulting documentation, yet I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Which line is the error referring to?

Comment: Thanks for your note! Already edited.
```Image.Image.paste(ImageOps.colorize(digit_rotated, (0,0,0), (255,255,255)), (x,6), digit_rotated).```

Comment: How do you know that the error is not from the `Image.Image.paste` method?

Comment: I should add that I know precisely that it is thrown by the paste method. But am still considering any other error sources

Comment: So it is from `paste` and not from `colorize`?

Comment: It seem to be from `paste`, right

Comment: How do you know that? Before you said that it was from `colorize`.

Comment: `paste` is a method of the `Image` class; you're trying to invoke it as a class method, rather than on an instance of `Image`.  So what image are you trying to paste onto here?

Comment: Before that I didn't clarify which method caused the problem, that's my mistake. I've tested the `colorize` separately and it seems to work fine outside of the nested line @mkrieger1

Comment: @jasonharper yep, that seems to be the source of problem. Much appreciated. Mind leaving a proper response then?